# Issue when I try to open my partner's solution (WPF application)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I made a WPF project on Visual Studio 2015. This project include some nuget package like LiveCharts, LiveCharts.WPF, MaterialDesignThemes, Newtonsoft.JSON and RestSharp.
I share my project to my partner but when he opens the solution he has got three errors : 
[image: Here are the errors]

We check some solutions on the web but nothing worked.

Thanks !!

Comment: what's project location full path?

Comment: @AkashKC on my computer or on his computer ?

Comment: your partner computer

Comment: @AkashKC a big one Thanks for your help ! I try the FINDarkside's solution and it works

Comment: I think, you know the issue. It's due to long path exceeding than VS limitation. So, you need to locate your project with short path

Comment: @AkashKC yes !!

Comment: We didn't know that the issue is due to the project location. We thought it was about nuget package. @Clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has limitations on file path length, you need to move the project to folder that has smaller path length.